# Customization of MUI Drawer Backdrop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, navigation-drawer, styled-components

I want to change the color of backdrop of MUI drawer.

I tried changing the color of backdrop using styled as given below:

```
const DrawerStyle = styled(Drawer) ({
 '& .MuiBackdrop-root' : {
   background: 'blue'
   opacity: 0.5
 }
})
```

The background color was working ,but I am unable to set the opacity.
I inspected the elements to see the styles and see what was going wrong

Image :

[image]

Actually the initial opacity is being given preference not the one I set. How to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get opacity to work either, but you can make the color have the opacity in it, like this. `blue` in rgb is: rgba(0, 0, 255) and 0.5 opacity is 50% opacity (0 is 0% opacity aka no color, 1 is 100% opacity aka completely blue)

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)',
```